# How to use static hostname instead of transient hostname?

Tags: fedora, hostname

Recently I have installed Fedora 33-workstation on my machine. The first thing I was noticed was about hostname in the terminal. It is shown as `myname@dhcppc2`. I was wondering why `dhcppc2`? After running `hostnamectl status | grep hostname`, I figured out that my system is using transient hostname, as the output was:

```
Static hostname: localhost.localdomain
Transient hostname: dhcppc2
```

Based on my prior experiences, I used to see static hostname in the terminal. Also I thought that `systemd` determines the hostname if `/etc/hostname` is unavailable, but in my system running `cat /etc/hostname` shows `localhost.localdomain`.

Would you please let me know that why my system is using transient hostname and how can I use static hostname rather than the transient one?

Answer (score 1):

Disable DHCP for changing your hostname ; append the above to **dhcpcd.conf**:

```
nohook hostname
```

Then set a permanent hostname entry :

```
hostnamectl set-hostname --static "<hostname>"
```